# jquery sort plugin not working

Tags: jquery

hi i tried this [jquery sort plugin](https://github.com/bmar/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js) with my tables, the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLwMC/7/) is here but as you can see it is not working. All i am trying to is sort the names in the  within the  of an ht of the what am i missing?

```
<tbody>

        <tr>
           <td><a id="17" href="/clients/17/">George Bush</a></td>
          </tr>
    <br><br><br>
        <tr>
         <td><a id="11" href="/clients/14/">Barak Obama</a></td>
       </tr>
        <br><br><br>
        <tr>
         <td><a id="14" href="/clients/14/">Bill Clinton</a></td>
       </tr>

</tbody>
<br><br><br>
<a href="#" id="sort-presi" class="button">Sort Presidents</a>
```

​

Comment: first off, in your fiddle you're trying to add a click event to an id that doesn't exist, and also btw your html is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your HTML is badly formed
- Your selector is wrong (selecting `#sort-clients` when your link is `#sort-presi`)

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8CrEs/1/) with these issues fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your click event calls id #sort-clients, while the sort link in the HTML has the id #sort-presi. Try to remove all table elements from your HTML, including tbody, and replace them with divs, it worked just fine when I tested it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NwP7/) it will solve all your problem :

**Note:** the fiddle you gave have the id of link is sort-clients in jquery function and sort-presi in html which are not similart how it will call the function when id are not same.

try the fiddle i gave in which (table based as per your requirement) you have to click on fruit or quantity to sort the elements.

Comment: people are here to help the community not to listen abuses from you side its better to improve your attitude or get lost.